# Windows Explorer like folder tree browser

Tags: c++, windows, treeview, wxwidgets, directory

I am trying to implement a platform independent file/directory tree browser. Basically, I am trying to replicate windows explorer's tree control to browse the computer. However, I can't figure out how to find the "Desktop" or "My Computer" folder string (It changes in every pc and os type, version and language). If I can find a way to get the topmost folder string, than I can traverse down and populate the tree hopefully. Is there a registry string somewhere?

Initially, I will only target MS Windows os'es (XP, Vista, etc) but later I plan to support Linux and Macs as well. I use wxWidgets for my GUI but I am open to all suggestions for this specific problem. Oh, and I am using C++ in VS2008.

Comment: You're probably going to stumble here; "My Computer" and "Desktop" are Windows-specific and not portable. Furthermore, you can't trivially traverse them.

Comment: Assuming Windows-only, do you want to get the string "Desktop" localized?  Or do you want the path to the Desktop folder?

Comment: MSalters: I realized what you pointed out after playing with SH methods you pointed out. 

crb: I just wanted the path to the desktop.

But, finally, I am more inclined to use wxGenericDirCtrl in wxWidgets, which is portable but only gives me my disks as a tree.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring portability, what you need is the "PIDL" tree. PIDLs are generalizations of file paths. You can get the PIDLs for special folders with [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180.aspx). The desktop is `CSIDL_DESKTOP` (*not* `CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY`), My Computer is `CSIDL_DRIVES`.

To convert the PIDLs to names, have a look at [SHGetNameFromIDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762191.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx) function.