# Tree View not getting displayed

Tags: treeview, c++-cli

I was trying to create a treeview browser for my application but got stuck somewhere.

The treeview isn't getting displayed.

Code:

```
System::IO::DirectoryInfo^ info = gcnew System::IO::DirectoryInfo(path);
    System::IO::Directory^ dir;
    if (dir->Exists(path))
    {
        try
        {
            array<System::IO::DirectoryInfo^>^ dirs = info->GetDirectories();
            if (dirs->Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dirs->Length; i++)
                {
                    TreeNode^ node = treeView1->Nodes[0]->Nodes->Add(dirs[i]->Name);
                    node->ImageIndex = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < dirs[i]->GetFiles()->Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (dirs[i]->GetFiles()[j]->Exists)
                        {
                            TreeNode^ nodes = treeView1->Nodes[0]->Nodes[node->Index]->Nodes->Add(dirs[i]->GetFiles()[j]->Name);
                            nodes->ImageIndex = 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception^ e)
        {
            MessageBox::Show(e->Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you don't see the treeview at all then you posted the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use splitcontainer and fill in the first section with your data first?

How did you initialize the new treeview class?
Example:

```
    [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    [ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType::AutoDispatch)]
    [DockingAttribute(DockingBehavior::Ask)]
    public ref class TreeView : public Control
```

Then you can implement treeview and imageview. 
For example, ShGetFolderLocation is one way to pull file locations, for windows OS.

Remember you have to populate the view and tell the system to display it for you to see it.

Or just go to: [this earlier solution for the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726016/windows-explorer-like-folder-tree-browser)

Follow up with the code for nodemouse click or whatever input response you are looking for such as expand or close, go to link and so on.

Comment: I did a quick try-catch, and the error was: "The specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index." I have edited the code a bit.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set your search to use either tree-D for linux or FOLDERID_ *  for windows OS newer than Vista, to find the names and display them. Check the "KNOWNFOLDERID" parameters to see if that matches what you are looking for.